# Keep getting a "Traceback" error when running simple program

Tags: python

I am new to this and I really don't understand why this is happen.
I am trying to run this program:

```
            NumberToCheck=0
            check=2

            def checker():
                global NumberToCheck
                global check
                check=2
                while check < NumberToCheck:
                    if NumberToCheck % check == 0:
                        main()
                    check=check+1
                else:
                    divider()

            def main():
                global NumberToCheck
                while NumberToCheck < 600:
                    NumberToCheck=NumberToCheck+1
                    checker()

            def divider():
                if 600851475143 % NumberToCheck == 0:
                    print (NumberToCheck)
                    end()
                main()

            def end():
                print ("end")

            print ("start")
            main()
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
            start
            1
            71
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/marknorman/Documents/Problem 3.py", line 29, in <module>
main()
              File "/Users/marknorman/Documents/Problem 3.py", line 21, in main
checker()
              File "/Users/marknorman/Documents/Problem 3.py", line 15, in checker
divider()
              File "/Users/marknorman/Documents/Problem 3.py", line 26, in divider
main()
```

And this would go forever in what looks like a random order unless I stop it.

Help?

Comment: That's not the full error. We need to see the whole thing. Also, you should read [mcve]. We need to see the exact code you're running. In Python, indentation is super important, so it'll be worth your time to get that fixed.

Comment: It is infinite. I have left it running for several minutes and it keeps printing that out.

Comment: Well, for one thing `except Exception` is a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like the error is `Maximm recursion depth exceeded `

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `main()` in divider. You're getting infinite recursion because instead of returning to main naturally you are calling the `main()` method again which starts the process over again.

Also as a side note I would really suggest you stop using all these global variables. Return values from your functions instead

Here's a much simpler version that still uses a function. (For a problem like this you really don't even need functions anyway but it looks like you're trying to practice them)

```
def main():
    numberToCheck = 600851475143
    i = 2

    #infinite loop
    while 1:
        if isDivisibleBy(numberToCheck, i):
            # if our number is divisible print it out and stop the loop
            print(numberToCheck, "is divisible by", i)
            break
        i += 1 #increment i

def isDivisibleBy(dividend, divisor):
    if dividend % divisor == 0:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also note that the function isDivisibleBy could be shorted to just:

```
def isDivisibleBy(dividend, divisor):
    return dividend % divisor == 0
```

But I figured that would be a little confusing for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks! That's it.

Comment: I'll post an update with how you should refactor this code to not use global variables in a few minutes too

Comment: Looking forward to it! What is the problem with global variables?

Comment: I've updated my post. Instead of having global values that get referenced by the functions you should instead pass around values using return statements. There's a massive list of reasons why you shouldn't use global variables in a situation like this, mainly because they are indicative of poor design. Here's a much better explanation than I could ever give: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil